# CommandButton in visualforce component not triggering action in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, action

I have a few command buttons that are not calling the action as defined in the controller. The 'showPopup' method works, but the others do not. Log files show that the methods are not being invoked at all.

Here is the troublesome part of my vf page:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!showPopup}" value="Add Signatory"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
<apex:outputPanel id="tstpopup">
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
            <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="" id="theTabPanel">
                <apex:tab label="Select Contact From Salesforce" name="select" id="tabOne">
                    <apex:actionRegion>
                        <p>Select contact from Salesforce:
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedContact}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!contactOption}" />
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </p>
                        <p>Assign signing role: 
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRole}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!roleOption}" />
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </p>
                        <p>Set signing order: 
                            <apex:input type="number" value="{!selectedStep}"/>
                        </p>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Add Signatory" action="{!addSignatory}" rerender="tstpopup,chosenSigs"/>
                    </apex:actionRegion>
                </apex:tab>
                <apex:tab label="Custom contact" name="custom" id="tabTwo">
                    <apex:actionRegion>
                        <p>Title: <apex:inputText value="{!customTitle}"/></p>
                        <p>Surname: <apex:inputText value="{!customLastName}"/></p>
                        <p>Email: <apex:inputText value="{!customEmail}"/></p>
                        <p>Mobile: <apex:inputText value="{!customMobile}"/></p>
                        <p>Assign signing role: 
                            <apex:selectList value="{!selectedRole}" size="1">
                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!roleOption}" />
                            </apex:selectList>
                        </p>
                        <p>Set signing order: 
                            <apex:input type="number" value="{!selectedStep}"/>
                        </p>
                        <apex:commandButton value="Add Signatory" action="{!addCustomSignatory}" rerender="tstpopup,chosenSigs"/>
                    </apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:tab>
                </apex:tabPanel>
                <apex:actionRegion>
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!hidePopup}" value="Close" rerender="tstpopup,chosenSigs"/>
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:actionRegion>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!send}" value="Send"/>
    </apex:actionRegion>
```

and the controller:

```
public void showPopup() {
    system.debug('show popup');
    displayPopup = true;
}

public void hidePopup() {
    system.debug('hide popup');
    displayPopup = false;
}
public void addSignatory(){
        displayPopup = false;
        Contact c = [Select title, lastName, Id, email, mobilephone From Contact Where Id = :selectedContact];
        Signatory sig = new Signatory(c);
        sig.role = selectedRole;
        sig.step = selectedStep;
        signatories.add(sig);
    }



public void addCustomSignatory() {
        displayPopup = false;
        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.title = customTitle;
        c.lastName = customLastName;
        c.email = customEmail;
        c.mobilePhone = customMobile;
        insert c;
        system.debug(c);

        Signatory sig = new Signatory(c);
        sig.role = selectedRole;
        sig.step = selectedStep;
        signatories.add(sig);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some experimenting and I found the issue to arise from the usage of commandButtons inside the conditional rendered outputPanel.

I did too things: firstly, I replaced the outputPanel with pageBlock elements.
Secondly, I delegated the conditional page rendering to a javascript function.

Pop a comment below if you would like me to post the code.